# How to load window.open('url') once only PHP & JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My problem right now is the page is loading like a loop. it is popping pages non-stop , how can I load only once after i trigger the time <= 0 ? thank you.

here is what my code looks like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var timeleft = 10;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 10 - timeleft;
  timeleft -= 1;

if(timeleft <= 0)

    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    window.open("http://localhost/ppa/movies.php", "", "width=1500px,height=1000px",true);
  }, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: You’re aware that for most users, the popup blocker will prevent even the first of these windows from opening, right?

Comment: @04FS yes sir, im doing this for purpose only :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you forgot some `{}`'s and meant to write:

```js
{
    ...
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        window.open("http://localhost/ppa/movies.php", "",
                    "width=1500px,height=1000px",true);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: wait, do i still need to put the `true` ? at the end of the window.open?

Comment: I just copy & pasted your original code and added the missing block, nothing else.